# Tableview reloading data not working in uitableview

Tags: objective-c

As i am deleting the json data .whenever i am deleting the json data i have to remove that particular data in the tableview. Also whenever i trying to remove the data in the first row it throws the exception like "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 rows before the update'" and app getting crashed

can anyone suggest me what was problem in the following coding?

```
    - (IBAction)deletebutton:(id)sender {
    NSString *userid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"UserId"];
    NSString *encodeddistrictvalue = [selecteddistrictvalue stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
    NSString *encodedPanchaytvalue = [selectedpanchayatvalue stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
      NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my json url",encodeddistrictvalue,encodedPanchaytvalue,taxtypevariable,selctedassessmentno,userid];NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
          if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
          {
              NSDictionary *dictionaryvalue = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:NULL];
               NSString *code = [[dictionaryvalue objectForKey:@"code"] stringValue];
               NSLog(@"the response string value is %@",code);
              if ([code intValue]==1) {
                  NSLog(@"deletd sucessfully");
               UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                               alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                               message:@"Are u sure u want to delete the table data"
                                               preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                  UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                              actionWithTitle:@"yes"
                                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                               {
                                                   [assessmentnumber removeObject:selctedassessmentno ];
                                                   [self.tableview registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"expandingCell"];
                                                   [_tableview reloadData];
                                              }
                                                  }];
                  [alert addAction:yesButton];
                  [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                  alert.view.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

              }
          }


     } ];

   }
```

Comment: Too much code provided. Please edit your question down to an understandable amount.

Comment: sry for inconvenience sir .i edited my question pls check it

Comment: Do not reload the entire table view. Use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. And if you are using storyboard and prototype cells you don't need to register cells  at all.

Comment: can u pls provide any sample code for this

Answer (score 0):

put this viewDidLoad

```
[self.tableview registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"expandingCell"];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply if i put that in viewdidload i am getting the following exception" Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell numberlabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145c1f640'"

Comment: the array count might not be changed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use begin & end update:

```
    Table.beginUpdates()
    for i in 0 ..< sections[section].items.count
    {
        Table.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: i, section: section)], with: .automatic)
    }
    Table.endUpdates()
```